# Predecir "lpmatrix" de un modelo promedio calculado con MumIn (model averaged)

Tags: r

Estoy intentando utilizar la función predict con type `lpmatrix` con un objeto tipo `averaging` y tengo dos dudas, el script sería el siguiente:

```
full_gam <- gam (abundance ~ s(chla, k = 4) + s(g_chla, k = 4) +
                 s(sst, k = 4) + s(g_sst, k = 4),
                 offset = log (effort), family = nb, data = training)

gam_dredge <- dredge(full_gam, m.lim=c(1,4), beta = FALSE,
 
confset.95 <- get.models(gam_dredge,subset = cumsum(gam_dredge$weight) <= .95)

gam_avg <- model.avg(confset.95, revised.var = TRUE)

Xp <- predict(gam_avg, newdata, type="lpmatrix")

sim_coef <- rmvnorm (n_sim, as.numeric(coef(gam_avg)), gam_avg$Vp)
```

Sin embargo, a la hora de hacer la predicción obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> Xp <- predict(gam_avg, newdata, type="lpmatrix")
>
> Error in weighted.mean.default(newX[, i], ...) : 'x' and 'w' must have the same length
> ```

Y a la hora de hacer la simulación, no sé de dónde puedo obtener los valores Vp (parámetros de la matriz de covarianza) del model averaged.

Entiendo que puede ser debido a que dentro del objeto hay varios modelos, pero sabéis si pueden extraerse de alguna manera?

Gracias